# Allow communication between two networks through two routers

Tags: networking, router, subnet

I have the following setup
[image]

I would like Device A to be able to communicate with device B and vice versa. I have setup static routing on Router A, and Router B as follows:

- Router A: 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.17
- Router B: 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.1

What is strange is that Device B can ping Device A, but Device A cannot ping Device B; instead Device A returns `Destination Port Unreachable`.

Comment: We coudl do with seeing the route tables on each of `A` and `B`, but your topology is confusing. Looks like `A` has two interfaces on the same subnet, which is going to make a mess.  You should have a separate transit network between the two routers.

Comment: @SmallClanger the two interfaces on the same subnet are WLAN and LAN. It is quite normal for a consumer router to put the wifi network and wired LAN on the same subnet.

Comment: That's true, but if that's the case then `Router A` isn't actually doing any _routing_. Is `Router B`s WAN port allowing the inbound traffic? If this is consumer kit, then it's probably dropping new incoming connections by default, whereas it will accept the return traffic from `Device B`s ping.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely Router B is doing NAT, that is, translating Device B's IP address from `192.168.1.10` to `192.168.0.17`. This means that device B can ping device A, but not vice versa.

To fix the issue, disable NAT on router B and let it do normal IP packet forwarding.